# Adaptar código ToolTip a um jTextField já criado

Tags: java, swing

Encontrei este código que funciona bem para o botão:

```
public class CustomJToolTipTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public CustomJToolTipTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CustomJToolTipTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);


        JButton button = new JButton("button") {
            //override the JButtons createToolTip method
            @Override
            public JToolTip createToolTip() {
                return (new CustomJToolTip(this));
            }
        };
        button.setToolTipText("I am a button with custom tooltip");

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CustomJToolTip extends JToolTip {

    public CustomJToolTip(JComponent component) {
        super();
        setComponent(component);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Existe uma frame com os campos onde aplicar esse `ToolTip`.

Como adaptar o código para um campo ao invés de botão?

Comment: Esse daí seta um tooltip personalizado com cor preta e letras vermelhas. Você realmente precisa de um tooltip personalizado (com cores ou tamanhos diferentes, degradê, imagens, animações, ou seja lá o que for) ou colocar apenas um tooltip padrão com um texto a ser definido por você já está ótimo?

Comment: Para mim chega mudar a cor do background e das letras mas já vi vários exemplos por aí que até são duas ou três linhas de código mas no meu não funciona :S

Comment: Sim, eu também. Só queria saber se você só precisa do texto ou precisa de firulas também.

Comment: Só texto mesmo. Consegues mudar a cor só do background e do texto? Se sim como fizeste? Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Creio eu que seja muito mais simples criar uma *Tooltip* com HTML (ao invés do `JToolTip`). Vários componentes suportam HTML, faça o teste com um `JLabel`:

```
myJlabel.setText(
   "<html><p style='color:#ffffff;background:#000000'>Preto e Branco</p></html>"
);
```

---

A mesma coisa pode ser feita na `tooltip` de um `JTextField`. Basta você definir o valor como HTML no método `setToolTipText`. Um exemplo de bem simples:

```
String tooltipHtml =
   "<html><p style='background:#2ecc71;border:none;color:#ffffff;padding: 6px;width:200px'>"
   + "UAU! Eu sou uma Tooltip estilosa...</p></html>";
```

[image: imagem]

<sup>Somente um exemplo <s>bem feio</s> para ilustrar.</sup>

Basta ter um conhecimento básico em HTML e CSS. Não tenho informações sobre como anda o suporte da plataforma, isto é, se ela aceita propriedades mais recentes do CSS e HTML. Mas independente disso, dá pra fazer muita coisa, mesmo tendo somente o básico.

Se não quiser *setar* uma-a-uma, você pode criar um método que retorna uma `tooltip` estilizada por *default*, contendo a `String` para inserir no método `setToolTipText`

```
private String getDefaultToolTip(String message){
   return "<html><p style='background:#000000;color:#ffffff'>" + message + "</p></html>"; 
}

// E em algum lugar do código...
textField.setToolTipText(getDefaultToolTip("Olá"));
```

**Uma observação**: Cores devem conter o código Hexadecimal completo para funcionar. Definir `#fff` ao invés de `#ffffff` não funcionará.

#### código de teste

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ToolTip extends JFrame {

    public ToolTip() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Tooltip");
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setSize(300, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        String tooltipHtml =
        "<html><p style='background:#2ecc71;color:#ffffff;padding: 6px;width:200px'>"
                + "UAU! Eu sou uma Tooltip estilosa...</p></html>";

        JTextField tfTooltip = new JTextField("Eu tenho Tooltip");
        tfTooltip.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 35);
        tfTooltip.setToolTipText(tooltipHtml);
        getContentPane().add(tfTooltip);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ToolTip().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```